# How to sort and group data in mysql by 2 different columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table `cart` which structure is following: `id, item_id, session_id, date, num`, so I need rows to be grouped by session_id column and sorted by date column  in the same time, is it possible?

Comment: Please provide some sample table data and expected output.

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and your attempts to answer the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

```
... order by session_id, date
```

This will order firstly by session_id, and then by date. I believe that is what you want?

Comment: but the thing is I also want session_id's to be ordered by date too

Comment: They will be ordered by date as well, unless you have another field called session_date, then no it wont be ordered by that date as well... Can a session have many dates? Im guessing yes...

Comment: When you say you want it to be ordered by date aswell, do you really want two results in one table? eg:
sessionid1 date1
sessionid1 date2
sessionid2 date3
date1 sessionid1
date2 sessionid1
date3 sessionid2

Where the three first rows in ordered by sessionid, and the three last rows is ordered by date, also the columns has been switched. This is also possible with a join, but unsure if that is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
GROUP BY session_id ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You cant group by session_id and in the same time order by date.

You will get:

> ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

what you can do is:

> SELECT [session_id],[date]
>   From TableName
>   group by [session_id], [date]
>   order by [date] desc